# Excel: nested if with and/or

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I would like to 'translate' in excel the following condition:

```
if((A<0 & B<0) OR (B>= 0 & A >=0), ABS(B-A),A-B)
```

I have tried as follows:

```
if(or(and(A1<0, B1<0),(B1>=0, A1 >=0), ABS(B1-A1), A1-B1)
```

but it does not work.

Do you know why?

You can imagine the following as dataset

```
A   B

-0.2  -0.3
0.2   0.1
0.1   -0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `AND`:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1<0,B1<0),AND(A1>=0,B1>=0)),ABS(B1-A1),A1-B1)
```

[image]

Comment: In case of "." values in one of the two columns or in both, how should I change the code? I tried to add the condition in the AND but it gave me VALUE! error. I am going to mark the question in one minute

Comment: IF(OR(AND(A1<0,B1<0, AND(A1<>".",B1<>"."),AND(A1>=0,B1>=0,AND(A1<>".",B1<>".")),ABS(B1-A1),A1-B1)

Comment: To test if a number contains a decimal, you should do `=INT(A1)<>A1`. If I understand what you're trying to do, `=IF(AND(AND(A1=INT(A1),B1=INT(B1)),OR(AND(A1<0,B1<0),AND(A1>=0,B1>=0))),ABS(B1-A1),A1-B1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Little alternative:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(COUNTIF(A1:B1,"<0")),ABS(B1-A1),A1-B1)
```

Or rather:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:B1,"<0")=1,A1-B1,ABS(B1-A1))
```